# Does the Garmin G-1000 contain a database of airport information?

Tags: avionics, faa, aeronautical-charts, datasets, publications

Some modern avionics contain airport information similar to what is published on charts and in the FAA's [Airport/Facilities Directory](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/advanced/).

Does the G-1000 keep airport information in a database that can be accessed by the pilot and displayed on-screen in flight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Airport information can be displayed on the MFD under Waypoint Pages (WPT).

Comment: Thanks Chris.  On a side note, do you fly one regularly?  Would you mind checking something specific for me?  (there's a tie-in with my two recent questions...)

Comment: @MichaelHall I do not, no.